# WTV and DVR-MS television recordings, should I de-interlace or not?

Tags: video, conversion, ffmpeg, windows-media-center

Following on from [this question](https://superuser.com/q/369483/46099) (where I am converting WTV and DVR-MS television recordings into H.264/MPEG-4 AVC to cut down on space), given the output of `ffmpeg -i <filename>`, how can I work out whether or not I should de-interlace the converted file?

The output for one such file is displayed below:

```
Input #0, asf, from 'Episodes_BBC TWO_2012_06_29_21_59_00.dvr-ms':
  Metadata:
    DVR Index Granularity: 500
    WM/SubTitleDescription: 8/9. Matt's life continues to fall apart when he fal
ls foul of his fierce ex-wife. Beverly prepares to go on a second date with Morn
ing's brother Rob. Contains strong language.  Also in HD. [AD,S]
    genre           : Shows;Other Shows
    WM/OriginalReleaseTime: 0
    WM/MediaCredits : ;;;
    service_provider: BBC TWO
    service_name    : BBC TWO
    WM/MediaNetworkAffiliation: BBC TWO
    WM/MediaOriginalChannel: 2
    WM/MediaOriginalChannelSubNumber: 0
    WM/MediaOriginalBroadcastDateTime: 0001-01-01T00:00:00Z
    WM/MediaOriginalRunTime: 1991686
    WM/MediaIsStereo: 0
    WM/MediaIsRepeat: 0
    WM/MediaIsLive  : 0
    WM/MediaIsTape  : 0
    WM/MediaIsDelay : 0
    WM/MediaIsSubtitled: 0
    WM/MediaIsMovie : 0
    WM/MediaIsPremiere: 0
    WM/MediaIsFinale: 0
    WM/MediaIsSAP   : 0
    WM/MediaIsSport : 0
    WM/Provider     : Default
    WM/VideoClosedCaptioning: 0
    WM/WMRVEncodeTime: 6349638
    WM/WMRVSeriesUID: !GenericSeries!Episodes
    WM/WMRVServiceID: !Generated!73b6594426b64c11b54ca352d79bb758
    WM/WMRVProgramID: !Loaders!Glid!Programs!9018:4164:4287!60652
    WM/WMRVRequestID: 0
    WM/WMRVScheduleItemID: 0
    WM/WMRVQuality  : 0
    WM/WMRVOriginalSoftPrePadding: 360
    WM/WMRVOriginalSoftPostPadding: 60
    WM/WMRVHardPrePadding: 184
    WM/WMRVHardPostPadding: 0
    WM/WMRVATSCContent: 0
    WM/WMRVDTVContent: 1
    WM/WMRVHDContent: 0
    WM/WMRVEndTime  : 1844674
    WM/WMRVBitrate  : 1844674
    WM/WMRVKeepUntil: 0
    WM/WMRVActualSoftPrePadding: 382
    WM/WMRVActualSoftPostPadding: 63
    WM/WMRVContentProtected: 0
    WM/WMRVContentProtectedPercent: 0
    WM/WMRVExpirationDate: 1844674
    WM/WMRVExpirationSpan: 1844674
    WM/WMRVInBandRatingSystem: 255
    WM/WMRVInBandRatingLevel: 255
    WM/WMRVInBandRatingAttributes: 0
    WM/WMRVWatched  : 0
    WM/MediaThumbType: 3
    WMFSDKVersion   : 12.0.7601.17514
    WMFSDKNeeded    : 0.0.0.0000
    VBR Peak        : 159
    IsVBR           : 1
    title           : Episodes
  Duration: 00:31:56.21, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 2658 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Audio: mp2, 48000 Hz, stereo, s16, 256 kb/s
    Stream #0:1(eng): Unknown: none
    Stream #0:2(eng): Video: mpeg2video (DVR  / 0x20525644), yuv420p, 704x480 [S
AR 64:45 DAR 1408:675], 15000 kb/s, 25.03 fps, 125 tbr, 1k tbn, 50 tbc
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Quoting](http://ffmpeg-users.933282.n4.nabble.com/Interlaced-detection-td2333861.html) Carl-Eugen Hoyos, one of the FFmpeg developers (if I'm not mistaken, at least he's the most active person on the FFmpeg mailing list):

> Decoding is necessary to determine if the input is interlaced, 
>   if you you encode immediately or later is your decision...

So, no – you can't tell that on-the-fly. What you'd have to do is try to decode the video to reliably get the information.

While I don't see anything particular in your output, one could guess from the difference in [`tbc`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3199489/meaning-of-ffmpeg-output-tbc-tbn-tbr) and actual frame rate that interlacing is used for this particular video clip.

---

That being said, some containers might have the proper information about interlacing set. Check the [`mediainfo`](http://mediainfo.sourceforge.net/en) output for the video file and look for `Scan type` and `Scan order` metadata fields. The former should either show `interlaced` or `progressive`.

Comment: Thanks for the links. MediaInfo reports `Scan type: Interlaced` and `Scan order: Top Field First` so I'm guessing that I should de-interlace this.