# Transferring .wtv files from Windows 8 Pro Media Center to OS X

Tags: windows-8, ffmpeg, windows-media-center, handbrake, mythtv

Does anyone have a good way to do this using only OS X tools?  That is, I have a Windows 8 Pro box that has 1 job and 1 job only, record TV shows from it's cableCARD onto its hard drive.

The mac can view that hard drive and copy .wtv files over.  But then I've tried ffmpeg, handbrake, other video apps, but nothing seems to be able to get past the Windows 8 Pro .wtv encryption.  (I think there are lots of articles out there on how this is possible with Windows 7.)

There are lots of windows based programs that claim to convert .wtv files but I'd rather not mess with any windows software.  Looking for a mac solution, thanks.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/369483/how-do-i-convert-wtv-and-dvr-ms-files-into-a-smaller-standard-format?rq=1 has the required commands to do the conversion.  Does the command suggestion not work for you?

Comment: i'll try again, I wasn't able to even get windows to break out the .wtv files into a dvr-ms file without an error message about encryption.  But only from some channels.  I think it has to do with http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy_Control_Information

Answer (score 0):

The copy protection on the WTV files is tied in with your Windows installation. If you try to copy them to another computer they will not work. The conversion really needs to be done on the Windows PC.

You should refer to the question [How do I convert WTV (and DVR-MS) files into a smaller standard format?](https://superuser.com/q/369483/472). There are answers there that refer to using only the open source [ffmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/) (disclosure: one is mine) and it is not necessary to use a Windows-specific program.